# Psycopg2-binary issue

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

Using Django and using the psycopg2-binary library, and a postgres DB, when i try to makemigrations I get the following error--

````
```/Users/renoaverill/codePlatoon/week7/django-todo/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture```
````

any and all help will be much appriciated!

Comment: here is my pip list--Package         Version
--------------- -------
asgiref         3.4.1
Django          3.2.5
pip             21.1.1
psycopg2-binary 2.9.1
pytz            2021.1
setuptools      56.0.0
sqlparse        0.4.1

Comment: do you happen to be using a mac with the new silicon? If so, see: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1200

Answer (score 1):

Please reinstall psycopg2

1. `pip uninstall psycopg2`
2. `pip install psycopg2 --no-cache-dir`

psycopg2 2.9.1 works good for me on MacBook Air M1